# Flowtype not checking props on imported redux container

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, flowtype

I've come across a confusing behavior testing out flowtype(0.43.0) on a redux project, using the react-redux typing from the flow-typed repo.

```
// @flow
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  props: {
    value: string, 
    otherValue: string
  }
  render() {
    return <span>{ this.props.value && this.props.otherValue }</span>
  }
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {otherValue: "test"}
}
const ConnectedChildComponent = connect(mapStateToProps)(ChildComponent)
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <ConnectedChildComponent/>
  }
}
```

The above code performs the type inference as expected and reports an error in the usage in the parent, indicating that the "value" prop should be set.

However, when I move the container child code into a separate file I find that the typecheck does not happen (likely to to an implicit 'any' import)

```
// flowTestPatent.js
// @flow
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import ConnectedChildComponent from './flowTestChild'
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <ConnectedChildComponent/>
  }
}


//flowTestChild.js
// @flow
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

export class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  props: {
    value: string, 
    otherValue: string
  }
  render() {
    return <span>{ this.props.value && this.props.otherValue }</span>
  }
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {otherValue: "test"}
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ChildComponent)
```

The above code reports no errors when it seems like it should be equivalent to the first example. I would assume I am somehow performing the import incorrectly, but when I import the un-connected component instead, typechecking happens as expected. Can anybody help explain what's going on here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why there is a difference between having it in one file vs separate. If you check out out the [todos-flow example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/todos-flow/src/containers/FilterLink.js) in the redux repo, however, they do handle typing their containers a little bit differently.

Basically, you end up manually specifying types for the connector, which is the function connect returns. Unfortunately, typing HOC's in flow requires this sort of manual step at the moment because [$Diff doesn't quite work as would be ideal](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/3396).

So in your case, you would have

```
// @flow
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect, type Connector } from 'react-redux'

type Props = {
  value: string,
  otherValue: string,
}
type OwnProps = {
  value: string,
}

class ChildComponent extends Component {
  props: Props
  render() {
    return <span>{ this.props.value && this.props.otherValue }</span>
  }
}

function mapStateToProps() {
  return {
    otherValue: 'test',
  }
}

const connector: Connector<OwnProps, Props> = connect(mapStateToProps)
const ConnectedChildComponent = connector(ChildComponent)

class ParentComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return <ConnectedChildComponent />
  }
}
```

With the above code, I get an error

```
26: const connector: Connector<OwnProps, Props> = connect(mapStateToProps)
                                ^^^^^^^^ property `value`. Property not found in
31:     return <ConnectedChildComponent />
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ props of React element `ConnectedChildComponent`
```

Comment: your example isn't working for me. Even in the same file now I get no type checking on usages of the connected component. I am importing the "Connector" type as `import type {Connector} from 'react-redux'` and flow is reporting the code as correct.

Comment: Updated to include all code. As is, it will have a flow error. Add value prop to ConnectedChildComponent and the error is resolved.